# Human Readable JSON: aka Add spaces and breaks to json dump

Tags: php, json, var-dump

Is there a "simple" script somewhere that will take a json data and format it to make it more readable?

For example:

```
// $response is a json encoded string.
var_dump($response);
```

The above outputs everything on one line. I'd like for it to be indented and spaced to make it easier to read.

Comment: If this is just for reading JSON, perhaps a browser addon like JSONView ([chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc), [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/), [opera](https://github.com/fearphage/jsonview-opera)) would be useful instead? (There are lots of other similar addons too.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

It's 2017 and I think this should be the answer for anyone on a modern version of PHP.

Note that lots of options exist for how to encode the JSON string to your liking. From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):
`JSON_HEX_QUOT, JSON_HEX_TAG, JSON_HEX_AMP, JSON_HEX_APOS, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR`

Answer (score 21):

Note that `var_dump` and its terser cousin [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) *do* print newlines.

Bear in mind that newlines are not shown in HTML document by default. In an HTML context, you want this instead:

```
echo '<div style="font-family: monospace; white-space:pre;">';
echo htmlspecialchars(var_export($response));
echo '</div>';
```

In php 5.4+, you can simply use the `PRETTY_PRINT` flag of [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Again, in an HTML context, you'll have to wrap it as described above.

Comment: @Matt Anderson Thanks, added a note that mentions a newer php is required, and added `var_export`.

Comment: cool trick, but I'm using 5.3 currently... I will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 12):

Paste it into [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and click validate.

Comment: This seems to be the quickest easiest option... useful little tool. thanks!

Comment: My preference is this site: http://json.parser.online.fr/

That said, JavaScript has a nice JSON parsing function which performs this function. Would be nice to do have something similar in PHP too.

Answer (score 11):

Had a similar problem, in that I was posting a serialised javascript object to a php script and wished to save it to the server in a human-readable format.

Found [this post on the webdeveloper.com forum](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?s=98d9939728fbec722d8a654458f0995c&p=1111999&postcount=4) and tweaked the code very slightly to suit my own sensibilities (it takes a json encoded string):

```
function jsonToReadable($json){
    $tc = 0;        //tab count
    $r = '';        //result
    $q = false;     //quotes
    $t = "\t";      //tab
    $nl = "\n";     //new line

    for($i=0;$i<strlen($json);$i++){
        $c = $json[$i];
        if($c=='"' && $json[$i-1]!='\\') $q = !$q;
        if($q){
            $r .= $c;
            continue;
        }
        switch($c){
            case '{':
            case '[':
                $r .= $c . $nl . str_repeat($t, ++$tc);
                break;
            case '}':
            case ']':
                $r .= $nl . str_repeat($t, --$tc) . $c;
                break;
            case ',':
                $r .= $c;
                if($json[$i+1]!='{' && $json[$i+1]!='[') $r .= $nl . str_repeat($t, $tc);
                break;
            case ':':
                $r .= $c . ' ';
                break;
            default:
                $r .= $c;
        }
    }
    return $r;
}
```

passing in

```
{"object":{"array":["one","two"],"sub-object":{"one":"string","two":2}}}
```

returns

```
{
    "object": {
        "array": [
            "one",
            "two"
        ],
        "sub-object": {
            "one": "string",
            "two": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I loved this so much, I converted it to Java. Enjoy anyone who finds this. https://gist.github.com/PaulBGD/846d2c4503a7bfc5036a

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($response));
echo '</pre>';
```

Too simple?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it through `python -mjson.tool`.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of using python worked well for me. Here's some code to use this from PHP:

```
function jsonEncode( $data, $pretty = false ) {
    $str = json_encode($data);
    if( $pretty ) {
        $descriptorSpec = array(
                0 => array('pipe', 'r'),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
                1 => array('pipe', 'w'),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        );
        $fp = proc_open('/usr/bin/python -mjson.tool', $descriptorSpec, $pipes);
        fputs($pipes[0], $str);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        $str = '';
        while( !feof($pipes[1]) ) {
            $str .= $chunk = fgets($pipes[1], 1024);
        }
        fclose($pipes[1]);
    }
    return $str;
}
```